# Why is dbf-table still open, if using "with tbl.open()"?

Tags: python, dbf

I use Ethan Furmans dbf-python-module (v. 0.99.3). If I use this code:

```
import dbf
tbl = dbf.Table(os.path.join(db_pfad, tabelle + ".dbf"))
with tbl.open(mode=dbf.READ_ONLY) as tbl:
    for rec in tbl:
          ...
tbl.close()
```

... everything is running fine.
But for my understanding of using `with`-clause, the last line `tbl.close()` should be redundant and superfluous. Leaving the range of `with` should close the table - not?
Anyway: If I ommit that line, the table will be left open!

---

Is this a bug in dbf-module or something I didn't get right about `with`-clause in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `with` block is entered, the table is checked to see if it was already open, and if so leaves it open on exit -- and you are manually opening it with the `.open()` call.

What you want to do is:

```
tbl = ...
with tbl:
    # do stuff
```

That will open the table in read/write mode, and close it when done.  If you need it to be opened read-only, then there's no point in using `with`:

```
tbl = ...
tbl.open(dbf.READ_ONLY)
for rec in tbl:
    ...
table.close()
```

Comment: Thx for clarifying about the usage of "with" when working with tables! (I think, there's a typo, "table" should be "tbl"!?) My unterstanding is now: With "with" the table would be opened - no extra call of .open() needed. In this case the table is always open in read/write mode. My point of using "with" in read-only mode would be, that I don't have to care about closing the table after '#do stuff' - especially if there is a lot of stuff to do. To avoid the risk of accidentally change of data it might be preferrable to abstain from using "with" if just read-only access is needed.